# How to place the cursor at the start of text and move the focus to start, when using the MaterialUI Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have went through many stackoverflow questions regarding this, but did not get a working solution,
I was able to place the cursor at the start of the text, but however the focus was not moved to the start.
below is the component code,

```
<Input
    inputRef={this.inputRef}
    inputProps={{
        onFocus: e => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.inputRef.current)
                    this.inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
            }, 10);
        },
    }}
    autoFocus={true}
/>
```

[image]

The image shows that the cursor has been moved to the start (as it is not visible at the end), but the focus was not moved to the start, any solution for this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work when I tried in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dewdney-zdw6p?file=/src/App.js).

can you verify it in sandbox? and also update the question with any additional properties given to `Input` component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem, please try having a default long text value in the input box on mount, and try changing the focus position, but one clue I got from the sandbox is that, the text is focused to start when there is  blur event followed by a focus event.